JQ extract array id of an object
I have this input data :
{
    "list": {
        "1": {
            "attributes": {
                "content": [],
                "pageable": {
                    "pageNumber": 0,
                    "pageSize": 10
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "attributes": {
                "content": [
                    {
                        "id": "AZER"
                    }
                ],
                "pageable": {
                    "pageNumber": 0,
                    "pageSize": 10
                }
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "attributes": {
                "content": [
                    {
                        "id": "WXC"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "QSD"
                    }
                ],
                "pageable": {
                    "pageNumber": 0,
                    "pageSize": 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I need to use JQ to extract the id values into a new array, I try this:
.list[] | .attributes.content[].id
that's my results:
"AZER"

"WXC"

"QSD"

It's what i want but in 3 line and i need to have it in array
How can i make this results in an array like this:
["AZER","WXC","QSD"]


You can populate our own array:
[ .[][].attributes.content[]?.id ]

["AZER","WXC","QSD"]

Try it online

just wrap you jq query with syntax [${request}]
for sample
jq '[.list[] | .attributes.content[].id]' input.json

in your case the request became
[.list[] | .attributes.content[].id]


If you just want to extract all "id" values into an array, streaming is also an option.
[ tostream | select((.[0][-1]=="id") and (.|length==2)) | .[1] ]

Try it on jqplay.org.

Is this any different from [recurse|objects|select(has("id")).id]?

@oguzismail They both produce the same output for the OP's example.  I don't know which might be more efficient, but I like yours better.

In general, just wrap your query that produces a stream of the desired values into array brackets, and the output is an array of those values.
[.list[] | .attributes.content[].id]

Demo
Note that there's also a shortcut to [ .[] … ] called map(…):
.list | map(.attributes.content[].id)

Demo
Both output:
[
  "AZER",
  "WXC",
  "QSD"
]

Use the --compact-output (or -c) flag, to remove irrelevant whitespace, thus compacting the output into a single line: ["AZER","WXC","QSD"]
